# Select last record in one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I'm using ms-access and I have 2 tables tblAssets and tblauditlog I'm trying to get the last audit log of all assets that have an assetstatus = 6 which means they have been sold. The relationship between the two table is tblassets.assetid = tblauditlog.logaspectid , I've only got as far as getting all the audit logs for assets that have been sold but I am looking for the last record. I have a date field but when i use Max(tblauditlog.logtimestamp) it throws an error

I've tried using

```
SELECT <br>
r.assetid, <br>
r.assetcategory, <br>
r.assetstatus, <br>
sub2.logmessage, <br>
sub2.logtimestamp <br>
FROM <br>
     tblAssets as r <br>
LEFT JOIN <br> <br>
 (SELECT <br>
     sub1.logaspectid, <br>
     a2.logMessage, <br>
     a2.logtimestamp <br>
 FROM  <br>
       ( <br>
        SELECT <br>
         a1.logaspectid, <br>
         Max(a1,logtimestamp) AS MaxOfTimeStamp <br>
         FROM tblauditlog AS a1  <br>
         GROUP BY a1.logaspectid ) AS sub1  <br>
       INNER JOIN tblauditlog as a2  <br>
 ON  <br>
     (sub1.MaxOfTimeStamp = a2.logTimestamp) AND (sub1.logaspectid = a2.logaspectid)) AS sub2 <br>
ON r.assetid = sub2.logaspectid ;
```

The above gives me an error:

> Unable to execute query. Invalid operation or syntax using multi-value
>   field

This is what I have returning multiple records

```
SELECT tblAssets.assetID, tblAssets.assetCategory, tblAssets.assetModel,
       tblAssets.assetStatus, tblAuditLog.logAspectID, tblAuditLog.logMessage,
       tblAuditLog.logTimeStamp
FROM tblAssets
    LEFT JOIN tblAuditLog ON tblAssets.assetID = tblAuditLog.logAspectID
WHERE (((tblAssets.assetStatus)=6)
   AND ((tblAuditLog.logTimeStamp)>=#1/1/2017#));
```

I just want the last recorded log for all assetstatus = 6 which is sold.

Comment: Edit question to provide sample raw data and desired output. Perhaps you should explore TOP N query. http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#TopN

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a correlated subquery to get the latest audit log record.  Then you can check if this has the status you want:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM tblAssets as a INNER JOIN
     tblauditlog as al
     ON a.assetid = al.logaspectid
WHERE al.logtimestamp = (SELECT MAX(al2.logtimestamp)
                         FROM tblauditlog as al2
                         WHERE al2.logaspectid = al.logaspectid
                        ) AND
      al.assetstatus = 6 ;
```